# Uniqueness of Birkhoff Normal Form and KAM theory for Symplectomorphims

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, hamiltonian-mechanics

I am starting to work with Hamiltonian Dynamics and I have been taking a look at some of the basic stuff in KAM theory. I have posted part of this question at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510935/kam-theorem-for-symplectic-maps-using-generalized-implicit-function-theorems)  but as I did not get any response I am posting it here.

I am looking for  references on the uniqueness of the Birkhoff Normal Form (as a formal series) of a Hamiltonian, in a neighborhood of an invariant "KAM torus".

I am also interested in the KAM theory for exact symplectomorphisms, more precisely, I want to know if there is a proof of this kind of theorem using generalized implicit function theorems.  Actually any reference in KAM theory in this discrete setting would be appreciated as the bibliography I have found in this topic is quite limited.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to know if there is a proof of this kind of theorem using generalized implicit function theorems."

Yes, it does exist, see Section 7 of Zehnder, E. Generalized implicit function theorems with applications to some small divisor problems. II. Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 29 (1976), no. 1, 49--111. MR0426055